# My create view is neither saving the object nor redirecting to the next page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I made a create view that should be able to save an object and then redirect bit form some reasons the form is not valid and it's not saving the object. If anybody knows the answer then please write the whole answer with code.

My create view

```
class Submit_Property(generic.CreateView):
   model = models.Property
   form_class = forms.Property_Form
   template_name = 'profile_details/submit-property.html'
```

Here's the model for This

```
class Property(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')

STATUS_CHOICES = (
('RENT','Rent'),
('SALE','Sale'),
    )

status = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices = STATUS_CHOICES,default = 'Rent')

price = models.IntegerField()

area = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')

ROOM_CHOICES = (
('1','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','3'),
('4','4'),
('MORE','More'),
    )

rooms = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices = ROOM_CHOICES,default = '1')
BATHROOM_CHOICES = (
('1','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','3'),
('4','4'),
    )
bathroom = models.CharField(max_length = 210,choices = BATHROOM_CHOICES,default = '2')
address = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
state = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
code = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
images = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images',)
info = models.TextField(max_length = 1000,default = 'None')
parking = models.BooleanField(default = False,verbose_name = 'Parking')
air = models.BooleanField(default = False)
swimming = models.BooleanField(default = False)
laundry = models.BooleanField(default = False)
dealer_name = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'None')
dealer_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 210,default = 'abc@gmail.com')
dealer_number = models.CharField(max_length = 210,default = 'Not mentioned')
user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'user',default = True)
timpestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
category = models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name = 'categories',default = None)


def get_absolute_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
    return reverse('profile_details:property')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: are you printing the form errors in the template? The `CreateView` should return the bound form with errors, so you should always show these errors so the user knows what's wrong (and you). You say "the form is not valid", how do you know? what are the `form.errors`?

Comment: It's not showing me erros I tried for e.g {{form.title.non_field_errors}}

Comment: Put the method form_invalid on the view and try to see the errors, when you finished with the errors, you also need to put the success_url property on the view.

Comment: I saw the errors it says that user field is required but i want to give that a default value in the post form and that will be self.request.user

Comment: In that case exclude `user` from your form. And override the `form_valid` method of your `CreateView` to add the user before saving.

Comment: when i try to do form.instance.user = self.request.user I get an error:

Comment: I just solved it..

Comment: I wrote the answer by myself please rate so i can improve my rankings:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right here in form valid

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

But don't write like this

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return super(models.Property, self).form_valid(form)
```